# Is this equation solvable (by hand) and what do you call this equation?

Tags: maxima-minima

Is this equation solvable (by hand) and what do you call this equation?

$a = x - \min(b\, x, c)$

$a, b, c$ are known. We need to solve for $x$.

If it is, and I can get guidance as to what this is called, and where there are resources to find out how to solve, this, I'm happy to do this.

Comment: Does `*` mean the product?

Comment: You simply test each condition: $a=x-bx \text{if} bx<c$ and $a=x-c$ if $bx>c$.  For equality choose either of the condtions.  Solve for $x$ and test which condition holds.

Comment: @ResidentDementor yes, * is product.

Comment: Of course $x-\min(bx,c) = \max(x-bx,x-c)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on the comment by player100:

The function $f(x) = x-\min(bx,c) $ has two regions:

$f(x) = (1-b)x \quad \text{if } bx \le c$

$f(x) = x-c \quad \text{if } bx \gt c$

Setting $f(x) = a$ then we have

$x = \frac{a}{1-b} \quad \text{if } \frac{ab}{1-b} \le c$

$x = c+a \quad \text{if } b(c+a) \gt c$

Note that we can re-arrange the condition $b(c+a) \gt b$ as $ab \gt (1-b)c$, so the two conditions are mutually exclusive *if* $1-b > 0$ i.e. $b < 1$. So if $b< 1$ then the equation $f(x)=a$ has exactly one solution.

However, if $b > 1$ then the equation $f(x)=a$ will have two solutions if $ab > (1-b)c$, one solution if $ab = (1-b)c$ and no solutions if $ab < (1-b)c$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and solution!